# How to use SpinnerDateModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

This is my code for `Datespinner`

```
//DateOfBirth{
    DateOfBirth = new JLabel("Date Of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    DateOfBirth.setBounds(50,490,180,20);
    jpanel.add(DateOfBirth);

    Date date1 = new Date();
    dobmodel = new SpinnerDateModel(date1,null,null,Calendar.YEAR);
    dobspinner = new JSpinner(dobmodel);
    JSpinner.DateEditor ded = new JSpinner.DateEditor(dobspinner,"MM/dd/yyyy");
    dobspinner.setEditor(ded);
    dobspinner.setBounds(250, 490, 125, 20);
    jpanel.add(dobspinner);

    //I used a ChangeListener


    dobspinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e1) {
           int DateOfBirth1 = (int) ((JSpinner) e1.getSource()).getValue();
        }

        public void stateChanged1(ChangeEvent arg01) {

        }
    });
```

But I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer.

What should i do? I am stuck.

Comment: This is the problem:  `int DateOfBirth1 = (int) ((JSpinner) e1.getSource()).getValue();`  How are you expecting a date to be represented as an integer?

Comment: How can i cast date into integer?

Comment: A DOB should never be an integer. What exactly are you trying to do with the DOB?

Comment: I want to enter the DOB into a Jtable.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getValue()` would return a `Date` object, so you should cast `Date` rather than `int` on that and change the type of `DateofBirth1` to `Date`.